# add RxCpp library to cmake project

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc, cmake

I'd like to use [RxCpp](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp) on Linux (gcc), but I have trouble to add RxCpp library appropriately to my [cmake](https://cmake.org) project. I followed cloning and building instructions and ran:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp.git
cd RxCpp

mkdir projects/build
cd projects/build
cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -B. ../CMake
make
```

I tried to run `make install` but got:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Then, I noticed the file `libRxCpp.so` in my build directory and copied it:

```
cp libRxCpp.so /sw/RxCpp/2.3.0/
```

I created a new project in [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/), which uses cmake and modified `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(RxCpp_Example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# my try to add library RxCpp
set(RxCpp_Lib_PATH /sw/RxCpp/2.3.0/)    
find_library(RxCpp_Lib NAMES libRxCpp.so PATHS ${RxCpp_Lib_PATH})
target_link_libraries(RxCpp_Example ${RxCpp_Lib})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(RxCpp_Example ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

However, I get an error when updating the cmake project (or running cmake in terminal):

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "RxCpp_Example" which is not built
  by this project.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I add RxCpp library to my cmake project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called `target_link_libraries` before creating the target with `add_executable`. Change your cmake file like this:

```
find_library(RxCpp_Lib NAMES libRxCpp.so PATHS ${RxCpp_Lib_PATH})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(RxCpp_Example ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(RxCpp_Example ${RxCpp_Lib})
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I include RxCpp's header files? There is no directory `include`. Can I generate it anyway?

Comment: In a perfect world, RxCpp would have used [`install` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/install.html) to export a cmake module declaring an [imported target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries). You should either modify RxCpp's cmake to add this (so you will be able to make install), or create the imported target by yourself in your project. You started with finding the library. Find include directory with [`find_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/find_path.html)

Comment: I expect that all needed header files are in the source directory [`RxCpp/Rx/v2/src/rxcpp`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp/tree/master/Rx/v2/src/rxcpp). I copied this directory to `/sw/RxCpp/2.3.0/include/rxcpp`. Now I have to call `find_library`, `find_path` and then `add_library` (in the mentioned order). Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct :) `add_library` will be something like `add_library(RxCpp SHARED IMPORTED)` followed by a call `set_target_properties(RxCpp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${RxCpp_Lib} INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${RxCpp_Inc})`. Then use `target_link_libraries(RxCpp_Example RxCpp)`.

Comment: cmake runs without an error, but when I try to build the official [example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp#example) `rxcpp/rx.hpp` is not found.

Comment: How did you call `find_path`? Use `message` to show in console the contents of the variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125182/discussion-between-maiermic-and-wasthishelpful).